Identify first row with a condition
I have a table like this one:



doc_num
doc_lin
doc_type




DOC0001
1000
2


DOC0001
2000
3


DOC0001
3000
3


DOC0001
4000
1


DOC0001
5000
2


DOC0001
6000
3


DOC0001
7000
3



And I need to have a SQL view where for each row, if doc_type = 3, it returns me the doc_line of the first previous row with doc_type = 2
like so:



doc_num
doc_lin
doc_type
return




DOC0001
1000
2
1000


DOC0001
2000
3
1000


DOC0001
3000
3
1000


DOC0001
4000
1
4000


DOC0001
5000
2
5000


DOC0001
6000
3
5000


DOC0001
7000
3
5000




Previous - according to what? Ordered by doc_lin? What about different doc_num's? Add at least one more doc_num to make the problem clearer.

You can use window functions to avoid the triangular join, which might give you better performance:
SELECT  *
,   CASE WHEN doc_type = 3 THEN max(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN doc_lin END) OVER(partition BY doc_num ORDER BY doc_lin rows unbounded preceding) ELSE doc_lin END AS [return]
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'DOC0001', 1000, 2, 1000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 2000, 3, 1000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 3000, 3, 1000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 4000, 1, 4000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 5000, 2, 5000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 6000, 3, 5000)
    ,   (N'DOC0001', 7000, 3, 5000)
) t (doc_num,doc_lin,doc_type,[return expected])

max(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN doc_lin END) OVER(partition BY doc_num ORDER BY doc_lin rows unbounded preceding) retrieves the maximum value where there's a return by looking back all rows until the current one.

@MatBailie hmm, but if it decreases, how would sql know which return he's looking for? There's no other ordered column besides doc_line, how does one calculates "last"? I guess the question is a bit too vague

No, I misread the question. You're right :) Deleting comments.


if doc_type = 3, it returns me the doc_line of the first previous row with doc_type = 2

Then use a CASE expression to check whether doc_type = 3, and in that case select that value.
select
  doc_num,
  doc_lin,
  doc_type,
  case when doc_type = 3 then
    (
      select top(1) doc_lin
      from mytable other
      where other.doc_num = mytable.doc_num
        and other.doc_lin < mytable.doc_lin
        and other.doc_type = 2
      order by doc_lin desc
    )
  else
    doc_lin
  end as return
from mytable
order by doc_num, doc_lin;

Using a subquery with a TOP clause is a general approach to get the last/best row. As doc_lin is both the sort key and the value you are interested in here, however, you can simplify  select top(1) doc_lin ... order by doc_lin desc to select max(doc_lin) ....

Here is one approach using window functions:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY doc_lin) cnt
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN doc_lin END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cnt) [return]
    FROM cte
)

SELECT doc_num, doc_lin, doc_type,
       CASE WHEN doc_type = 3 THEN [return] ELSE doc_lin END AS [return]
FROM cte2
ORDER BY doc_lin;

Demo
Explanation:
The first CTE above forms a pseudo group of all records which belong to a certain latest record having doc_type = 2.  Then, we use conditional aggregation within each such group to find the most recent doc_lin value.  In the final select, we use this recent doc_lin value from the latest doc_type = 2 record, for those records having doc_type = 3.  Otherwise, we simply report the current doc_lin value.

@DaleK The table markdown would be verbatim what the question above already has.  This is just a screenshot included as evidence that the demo is working.  If it cannot render, there would be a line saying that image is missing.
